# Grails Resources Plugin: how to inline JavaScript via resources boundles defined in ApplicationResources.groovy?

Tags: grails

I need to pass variables from Config.groovy to JavaScript on several pages that uses same resource bundle.
I have JS lib that needs config option 'appId'. The problem is that JS and CSS files of this lib are declared as resources bundles in ApplicationResources.groovy and I can't control on which page they are used.

There is tag . Body of this tag will be included to page body as inline JavaScript. Great.
But it requires manually repeat this section with same content on each page. That's why it does not suit me.

E.g. I need something like this in ApplicationResources.groovy:

```
modules = {
    myJSPlugin {
        dependsOn 'jquery'
        resource url:'/js/core.js', disposition: 'head'
        // this is inline JS here
        resource type: 'inlineJs', body: {-> "var appId = 22;"}
    }
}
```

```
How can I achieve this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you provide

`<r:script>var appId = 22;</r:script>`

either in the body or disposed in head, inside main layout, shouldn't it be available to the child pages whichever uses the layout?

@Resource [r:script](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-resources/ref/Tags/script.html)